# Count characters for last 50 rows

Tags: php

I have this query running on a script.
I'm like to get a total of characters from last 50 rows of **file_title**
column.

Query run, but SUM all rows, i need only and not last 50.

```
Table files:
file_id, file_title, file_user
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

        $characters_qty = mysql_query("
            SELECT *
                FROM (
                        SELECT      *,
                        SUM         (CHAR_LENGTH(file_title)) AS foo
                        FROM        files
                        ORDER BY    file_id DESC
                        LIMIT       50              
            )
            ORDER BY file_id

        ");
        $res_characters = mysql_fetch_assoc($characters_qty );
        $total_qty = $res_characters['foo'];
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: *to get a total of characters from last 50 rows* VS *i need only and not last 50*, how that?

Comment: @roman, you mean this? SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY auto_incremented_id DESC LIMIT n

Comment: `SELECT SUM(LENGTH(`file_title`)) AS char_count FROM files ORDER BY file_id DESC limit 50`?